Issue with ANSI Escape Codes in Output When Running Shell Script via Python Subprocess
I have a bioinformatics pipeline that builds and runs .sh files in Python. I run the .sh through a subprocess module so I can use parallel computing.
This worked about 6 months ago, but now has stopped. It seems like for some reason the ANSI escape codes are being inserted in the command line arguments in some of the Perl scripts used in the pipeline. I'll paste the line in the error logs where teh code fails from a script run through Python's subprocess:
2024-06-27 13:16:29 /Users/kevin/VirVarSeq/map_vs_consensus.pl  !---- Paired end mapping using [35m./Sample_Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314/Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314_R1.fastq.gz[m[m [35m./Sample_Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314/Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314_R2.fastq.gz[m[m ...
[M::bwa_idx_load_from_disk] read 0 ALT contigs
[E::main_mem] fail to open file `[35m./Sample_Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314/Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314_R1.fastq.gz[m[m'.

However if I just run the EXACT same script from the shell, it runs fine! I don't know why. Here is the same line from the log when I run the .sh file from the terminal:
2024-06-27 13:08:04 /Users/kevin/VirVarSeq/map_vs_consensus.pl  !---- Paired end mapping using ./Sample_Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314/Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314_R1.fastq.gz ./Sample_Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314/Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314_R2.fastq.gz ...
[M::bwa_idx_load_from_disk] read 0 ALT contigs
[M::process] read 41262 sequences (6098025 bp)...

I've tried starting the subprocess a few ways and still having this same error. Like I said, if I just run the script in the zsh shell it runs without issue.
This is the .sh script up to the point where it errors:
#!/bin/zsh
#VirVarSeq Pipeline

seq_header=Q23.17-NHG_3BNC-10_E8-240314
ln -s /Users/kevin/VirVarSeq/R ./
mkdir Sample_$seq_header
ln -s $PWD/*fastq.gz ./Sample_$seq_header
echo $seq_header > samples.txt

#make directories as VirVar would have:
mkdir VirVarResults
mkdir VirVarResults/codon_table
mkdir VirVarResults/consensus
mkdir VirVarResults/map_vs_consensus
mkdir VirVarResults/map_vs_ref
mkdir VirVarResults/mixture_model

#use bam file from lofreq mapping (unfortunately need it in SAM format):
samtools view -h -o ./VirVarResults/map_vs_ref/$seq_header.sam $seq_header.bam "Q23.17-NHG"

indir=.
outdir=./VirVarResults
samples=./samples.txt
ref=/Users/kevin/Documents/Bienasz_Lab/HIV1_bNab_Env_Escape/Sequencing_analysis/Variant_calling/3BNC117/240621_MiSeqRun/Reference_Genomes/Q23.17-NHG.fasta
startpos=6170
endpos=8829
region_start=6221
region_len=853
qv=0

consensus.pl --samplelist $samples --ref $ref --indir $indir --outdir $outdir --start $startpos --end $endpos >> VirVarSeq.log 2>&1



How are the log messages being written? ANSI escape sequences are usually only sent to a terminal, not to log files.

You'll need to post the code that's producing the log messages.

Thank you! I've posed the .sh script now

What part of the script is writing the log messages?

Is the output you're showing from VirVarSeq.log?

The copy/paste is probably incomplete because you can't properly copy the actual escape character. If it is present in the logs, maybe use a symbolic representation like ^[.

yes, the output I showed is from the VirVarSeq.log
I'll post a picture of what the log looks like in a plaintext editor

For the record, that's a Zsh script. Usually you would not use .sh on scripts which aren't POSIX sh scripts (and actually probably not then, either).

Thanks tripleee! I'm more of a hobbiest with this stuff. What would be the proper suffix? (if any)

The shell script is probably uninteresting; the escape codes come from samtools and/or within the Perl script. Sometimes these tools have options which allow you to control whether they will output color codes; the changed behavior suggests that a new version was installed. (Though usually you'd hope that a new version should fix problems like these, not introduce them.)

There is no particular reason to have an extension on your script at all. It helps e.g. Github understand which language it's in, but if it's just an interactive script for your private use, call it whatever you like. ls doesn't have an extension either (and if it did, that would be annoying).

Thanks for your comments! Can you explain why the .sh file runs fine (without errors) when I run it directly from the terminal? I only get these weird escape characters when I'm running it from python

To me, it looks like consensus.pl is producing the ansi codes, so I would have a closer look into this program.

Thanks user1934428. I thought the same thing, but it doesn't produce those codes when the program is just ran normally through the terminal. It has to be something to do with how python is calling/handeling inputs/outputs, or using different permissions/underlying architecture...

So I didn't really figure this out, so I just ended up writing a shell script to iterate through the directories and run my scripts locally. Unfortunately it got rid of the ability to run things in parallel, but that's okay for now.
Unfortunately I can't figure out why running the scripts through python's subprocess module causes these ANSI escape characters... Maybe something with a different PATH using slightly different versions of samtools or something.
